# Accordion AJAX JSON content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following html structure

```
<div class="accordion-container">
    <ul class="accordion">
      <li class="accordion-header">
        <a class="is-active link">Accordion header<i class="accordion-header-icon"></i></a>
        <div class="accordion-content js-accordion-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, quos!</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="accordion-header">
        <a class="link">Accordion header<i class="accordion-header-icon"></i></a>
        <div class="accordion-content js-accordion-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla sed ducimus iusto, atque veniam, laborum ratione quibusdam sapiente. Sint.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="accordion-header">
        <a class="link">Accordion header<i class="accordion-header-icon"></i></a>
        <div class="accordion-content js-accordion-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla sed ducimus iusto, atque veniam, laborum ratione quibusdam sapiente. Sint.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="accordion-header">
        <a class="link">Accordion header<i class="accordion-header-icon"></i></a>
        <div class="accordion-content js-accordion-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla sed ducimus iusto, atque veniam, laborum ratione quibusdam sapiente. Sint.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and this css

```
.accordion-content {
  display: none; }
```

I'm trying to populate the accordion-content with content from a json file only when click on each accordion header (.link)

I've tried this but it doesn't work as intended. When I click on a header it populates all the other accordion-content.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.accordion').each(function (index) {
    $(this).children('li').first().children('a').addClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-open').show();
  });

  $('.accordion').on('click', 'li > a', function (event) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var accordionTabs = $(this).closest('.accordion');
      accordionTabs.find('.is-open').removeClass('is-open').slideUp('fast');

      $(this).next().toggleClass('is-open').slideToggle('fast');
      accordionTabs.find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');

      $(this).addClass('is-active').closest('.accordion-content', function () {
        $.getJSON('public/js/result.json', function (jd) {
        $('.js-accordion-content').html('<p>Name: ' + jd.name + '</p>');
        $('.js-accordion-content').append('<p>Age : ' + jd.age+ '</p>');
        $('.js-accordion-content').append('<p>Sex: ' + jd.sex+ '</p>');
      });  
    });
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

The json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Zara Ali",
  "age" : "67",
  "sex": "female"
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(jd)` inside the `.getJSON` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `closest` method does not accept an anonymous function as the 2nd argument, and therefore this never fires in your code.

```
$(this).addClass('is-active').closest('.accordion-content', function () {
```

I don't see you doing anything with the `.accordion-content` selector anyway, so just omit it.

```
$(this).addClass('is-active');
$.getJSON(....
```

You will also need to cache a reference to your element that fired the click event in order to reference in within the result of your ajax callback:

```
var self = $(this);
```

We need to natively wrap it as a jQuery object because the 2nd argument we pass in as context needs to apply `.parent()` in order to actually get the `.js-accordion-content` element.

```
$('.js-accordion-content', self.parent()).html('<p>Name: ' + jd.name + '</p>');
$('.js-accordion-content', self.parent()).append('<p>Age : ' + jd.age + '</p>');
$('.js-accordion-content', self.parent()).append('<p>Sex: ' + jd.sex + '</p>');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kb678zd/)

Comment: I've changed the code as you suggested and now I get this in console Object {name: "Zara Ali", age: "67", sex: "female"} but the content still load on all the other accordion-content div, instead of only inside the one that I clicked.

Comment: @cosmin because you also need to do the whole `var self = this;` and `$('.js-accordion-content', self)` as suggested in the above answer as well. Your problem is really a mixture of both of our answers.

Comment: I've just tried that too, but now I'm not getting any content from json into the accordion-content.

Comment: @CosminAnca Resolved. Check the edit and the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The query ".js-accordion-content" is ambiguous to all similar elements with the same class name. Isolate it to the current "accordion"

replace:

```
  $(this).addClass('is-active').closest('.accordion-content', function () {
    $.getJSON('public/js/result.json', function (jd) {
    $('.js-accordion-content').html('<p>Name: ' + jd.name + '</p>');
    $('.js-accordion-content').append('<p>Age : ' + jd.age+ '</p>');
    $('.js-accordion-content').append('<p>Sex: ' + jd.sex+ '</p>');
  });
```

with

```
 var self = this;
  $(this).addClass('is-active').closest('.accordion-content', function () {
    $.getJSON('public/js/result.json', function (jd) {
    $('.js-accordion-content', self).html('<p>Name: ' + jd.name + '</p>');
    $('.js-accordion-content', self).append('<p>Age : ' + jd.age+ '</p>');
    $('.js-accordion-content', self).append('<p>Sex: ' + jd.sex+ '</p>');
  });
```

Notice the use of `self` referencing the accordion.